# Transposing PCR 96 well plate to single column format

Tags: r, transpose, genetics

PCR plates work on a coordinate system similar to an X-Y coordinate system. I would like to convert a 96-well PCR plate from this X-Y coordinate system  (row and column format) to a single column only format, combining the x-y system together (i.e Row B and Column 12 = B12).

The first dataset provided below, called "pcr_plate", is the format of a 96-well PCR plate.

The second dataset, called "sample_transposed_plate" is an example of the desired outcome.

I've tried classical approaches to transposing data, using code from the follwing packages:

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

In addition to transform(data.frame, ... )

However, I am confused how to write a code that starts from Row A column 1:12, followed by Row B column 1:12, etc.. while keeping the respective sample (aka well) in an adjacent column

two sample working data sets:

```
pcr_plate <- read.table ("https://pastebin.com/raw/bGhzj5dU", header = T, sep = "")


sample_transposed_plate <- read.table ("https://pastebin.com/raw/xyzv9cvH", header=T, sep = "") # example of desired outcome
```

Logically, given there are 96-wells, I should have 96 lines of data in the end (97 with a header).  First column would be "location", and second column would be "sample"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use a typical `gather` to convert from wide to long data:

```
library(tidyverse)
pcr_plate <- read.table ("https://pastebin.com/raw/bGhzj5dU", header = T, sep = "")
sample_transposed_plate <- read.table ("https://pastebin.com/raw/xyzv9cvH", header=T, sep = "")

pcr_plate_long = pcr_plate %>%
  gather(number, content, -pcr.plate) %>%
  mutate(number = str_remove(number, "^X"),
         well_ID = paste0(pcr.plate, number)) %>%
  select(content, well_ID)
```

Comment: Hello  Thanks for your response.  It also works great.

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that we both posted the answer almost at the same time.

Comment: @Mojoesque, it looks like you beat me by a minute! Only difference is I arranged the columns and used `gsub` instead of `str_remove`. Great minds think alike ;). If I saw you posted this I would have just added the sorting as a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for (below)

- The first line transforms the data from wide to long
- The second line removes the "X" from the values and pastes it with the plate (letter),
- The third line selects your columns (and renames one)
- The fourth line is a way to arrange the data first by the letter, and then by the number in `well_ID`.

Let me know if this doesn't work or if you have any questions.

```
pcr_plate <- read.table ("https://pastebin.com/raw/bGhzj5dU", header = T, sep = "")

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

gather(pcr_plate, key = "key", value = "sample", -pcr.plate) %>%
  mutate(pcr.plate = paste0(pcr.plate, gsub("X", "", key))) %>%
  select(well_ID = pcr.plate, sample) %>%
  arrange(gsub("\\d", "", well_ID, as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", well_ID))))

   well_ID     sample
1       A1     1-TypA
2       A2     1-TypA
3       A3     2-TypA
4       A4     2-TypA
5       A5     3-TypA
6       A6     3-TypA
7       A7     4-TypA
8       A8     4-TypA
9       A9   H20-TypA
10     A10   H20-TypA
11     A11  PosA-TypA
12     A12  PosB-RP49
13      B1     1-TypB
14      B2     1-TypB
15      B3     2-TypB
16      B4     2-TypB
17      B5     3-TypB
18      B6     3-TypC
19      B7     4-TypB
20      B8     4-TypB
21      B9   H20-TypB
22     B10   H20-TypB
23     B11  PosA-TypA
24     B12  PosB-RP49
25      C1     1-TypC
26      C2     1-TypC
27      C3     2-TypC
28      C4     2-TypC
29      C5     3-TypC
30      C6     3-TypB
31      C7     4-TypC
32      C8     4-TypC
33      C9   H20-TypC
34     C10   H20-TypC
35     C11  PosA-RP49
36     C12   PosB-H20
37      D1     1-RPS5
38      D2     1-RPS5
39      D3     2-RPS5
40      D4     2-RPS5
41      D5     3-RPS5
42      D6     3-RPS5
43      D7     4-RPS5
44      D8     4-RPS5
45      D9   H20-RPS5
46     D10   H20-RPS5
47     D11  PosA-RP49
48     D12   PosB-H20
49      E1     1-RP49
50      E2     1-RP49
51      E3     2-RP49
52      E4     2-RP49
53      E5     3-RP49
54      E6     3-RP49
55      E7     4-RP49
56      E8     4-RP49
57      E9   H20-RP49
58     E10   H20-RP49
59     E11   PosA-H20
60     E12        H20
61      F1   1-F1430A
62      F2   1-F1430A
63      F3   2-F1430A
64      F4   2-F1430A
65      F5   3-F1430A
66      F6   3-F1430A
67      F7   4-F1430A
68      F8   4-F1430A
69      F9 H20-F1430A
70     F10 H20-F1430A
71     F11   PosA-H20
72     F12        H20
73      G1   1-F1409B
74      G2   1-F1409B
75      G3   2-F1409B
76      G4   2-F1409B
77      G5   3-F1409B
78      G6   3-F1409B
79      G7   4-F1409B
80      G8   4-F1409B
81      G9 H20-F1409B
82     G10 H20-F1409B
83     G11  PosB-TypA
84     G12        H20
85      H1      1-H20
86      H2      1-H20
87      H3      2-H20
88      H4      2-H20
89      H5      3-H20
90      H6      3-H20
91      H7      4-H20
92      H8      4-H20
93      H9    H20-H20
94     H10    H20-H20
95     H11  PosB-TypA
96     H12        H20
```

EDIT:

False alarm on my comment, it did work as intended. This is another way to do it though to get the same result. Let me know if you have questions!

```
gather(pcr_plate, key = "key", value = "sample", -pcr.plate) %>%
  mutate(key = as.numeric(gsub("X", "", key))) %>%
  arrange(pcr.plate, key) %>%
  mutate(pcr.plate = paste0(pcr.plate, key)) %>%
  select(well_ID = pcr.plate, sample)
```

Comment: Hello.  This is the exact response I am looking for.  I have tried those libraries in the past, sometimes with success, but find the code extremely difficult to comprehend (and therefore difficult to write) I will study your code and hope to get some sense of why it works to adapt it to future scripts.  Thank you for your quick help

Comment: Sure thing, @Andy. I tried to add an explanation but let me know if / what is still confusing.

Comment: Actually, @Andy, the last step needs to be fixed. It did not work as I intended it. I'll post an update once I fix it

Comment: Hello.  I appreciate the commented code!  I must have seen this last comment after you already fixed the issue, because from my end, the code works like I wanted it to, and I do not see any mistakes